# PWM on NVIDIA Jetson Nano Developer Kit

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pwm, sysfs, nvidia-jetson-nano

I'm working on a Jetson Nano for my MSc thesis.

At this time I have to control a camera using PWM signal generated from NVIDIA SBC, so after set PWM capability with their own tool (Jetson-IO), I'm trying to produce the signal.

I have been successful in camera control with Raspberry, and because of the similarity of Jetson with Raspberry (in particular about interfaces, pinout libraries and compatible peripherals/devices), I have been making comparisons between them.

So, I report here-after the discussion into NVIDIA Forum, and hope someone could help me.

https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/strange-behaviour-with-jetson-nano-devkit-pwm-signal/113004/18?u=jacopo

Thank you

Jacopo